# Video on sites are Jerky

Tags: pi-3, streaming-video, html5

I've got a problem with my Rpi 3 on a Raspbian. I want to show some videos from internet (HTML Videos), but when I display them (they are not even in full screen), it's all jerky. It plays 2 seconds of videos, then stop, then start again etc...

I've tried to add more memory to the GPU, even more than the CPU, but it doesn't help at all. My network connexion is ok, it's the same I use on my normal computer..

I'm using Chromium by the way, and on youtube, the video is working good...

Does anyone knows what the problem could be ?

Comment: Either those videos are too heavy for the RPi to handle, or they use codecs which are poor in Raspbian. Difficult to say more without knowing which videos you're talking about.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I've tried with H264 (mov and mp4) and MPEG2 (mpg).
Even with a 10seconds videos, it is slow.

Comment: H264 can be quite computationally intensive with high profile.

Comment: Ok. And what about Mpeg2 ? I've not been able to play on browser nor on  omxplayer, look like it doesn't know about .mpg videos ?

Answer (score 1):

MPEG2 playback speed on the RPi can be increased by buying a [license](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/) for the hardware codec. You will need to write down the serial number of your board from `/proc/cpuinfo`, which will be required at the time of purchase.

Disclamer: I have no means to know whether your particular video will be supported, or whether the performance boost will be significant enough to provide smooth playback.

Comment: Ok Dmitry. Is the license usable for multiple RPi or only one ?

Comment: @Ezhno Only one - that's why you need the serial number to buy it. They give you the activation key to put in your `config.txt`

Comment: What H264 profile do you suggest ? What video have you been using ?